# What is the real story of Cheraman Perumal who witnessed the splitting of moon?

Tags: history, nayanar

Cheraman perumal was one among 63 Nayanars and while scrolling through internet, I read that [he witnessed the splitting of the moon](http://theislamshow.weebly.com/the-proof-of-splitting-of-moon---witnessed-by-indian-king.html), a miracle claimed to have been made by Muhammad, following which he went to Mecca and embraced Islam.

What is the real story regarding this incident? If he really converted to Islam, then Sekkizhar wouldn't have written about him in Periya Puranam.

Comment: This Wikipedia page provides a lot of information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheraman_Perumal_myths Basically it's unclear whether the Muslim story is true or not.  In any case, it's worth noting that every single emperor of the Chera empire was known by the title "Cheraman Perumal", so it's possible that one Chera emperor was a Nayanar and another Chera emperor converted to Islam.  (Yet another Chera emperor, by the way, was an Alwar, namely Kulasekhara Alwar.)

Comment: I think only one king embraced the title. @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: What do you mean "embraced" the title?  In any case, in the literature you'll find lots of Chera emperors referred to as Cheraman Perumal.